# Setting a number in a multidimensional array equal to a word

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Currently writing a java program for `Tomasulo's Algorithm`. Im trying to take a number from a `multidimensional` array set it to a word.

This is reading from a text file that looks like this:

```
10

7

0 2 2 1

0 3 3 2

0 4 2 3

2 5 2 4

2 6 3 5

3 7 3 4
```

The first two lines are bypassed for other things but then after that I would like the first number of each of the lines to be set to a word such as `'0'` to `'add'`, `'1'` to `'sub'`, `'2'` to `'mult'`, and `'3'` to `'div'`

How do I go about this?

```
   int IntQue[][] = new int[10][4];

    Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(file);
    n = 0; // for the number of instructions
    displayCycle = 0; // cycle to be displayed

    if (scanInt.hasNext()) {
        n = scanInt.nextInt(); // number of instructions taken from file
        displayCycle = scanInt.nextInt(); // cycle number taken from file
    }


            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            IntQue[i][j] = scanInt.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would scan it as String instead of `nextInt()` and then use `String.replace()`

Comment: If you want to replace a number with a string, you need an `Object[][]`, not an `int[][]`. The `Object[][]` can hold `String` as well as `Integer` objects (indeed, objects of any type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of integer array you can have a string array to set the values based on the integer value you are reading from the file.

Below is the code to fulfill your requirement:

```
    public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String stringArray[][] = new String[10][4];

        Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(new File("File Path"));
        int n = 0; // for the number of instructions
        int displayCycle = 0; // cycle to be displayed

        if (scanInt.hasNext()) {
            n = scanInt.nextInt(); // number of instructions taken from file
            displayCycle = scanInt.nextInt(); // cycle number taken from file
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (scanInt.hasNext()) {
                    stringArray[i][j] = getStringValue(scanInt.nextInt());
                }
            }
        }

        // Printing the data
        for (String[] strArray : stringArray) {
            for (String s : strArray) {
                System.out.print(s+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static String getStringValue(int number) {
        String value = null;
        switch (number) {
            case 0:
                value = "add";
                break;
            case 1:
                value = "sub";
                break;
            case 2:
                value = "mult";
                break;
            case 3:
                value = "div";
                break;
            default:
                value = "";
                break;
        }
        return  value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well for converting the numbers over to the words, but how would I get the following 3 numbers after the first number in the line to display only the number?

Comment: Can you please provide +1 for my answer if it's helps you and can you please elaborate on your question.

Comment: The output looks something like this      |                                                         
add mult mult sub    |     
add div div mult    |     
add  mult div    |     
mult  mult     |     
mult  div     |     
div  div     |     
div       |     
sub sub mult     |     
mult mult  sub    |     
add div mult sub     |                                                                                                     is there a way to make it so just the first number in each of the lines changes and the other numbers in the line will stay what they originally were?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a switch statement to handle this, since you're only handling maximum 10 possible outcomes (0-9). In each case I would store the converted values in a separate String array that can be indexed by the number of lines in your file. The following program should take care of everything including the storing of the trailing numbers:

Update: this program is actually very similar to the other submission but should answer the entire problem

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class TomasuloAlgorithimDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("C:/PathToFile/File.txt");
        Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(file);
        String line = "";
        int cycle = 0;

        //Initializations are specific to your example
        String[] convertedFirstNums = new String[6];
        int[][] nums = new int[8][3];

        while (scanInt.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanInt.nextLine();
            cycle++;
            if(cycle > 2) {//Only executes after first two lines are parsed

                //Grab first integer for conversion
                String firstNum = "" + line.toCharArray()[0];
                convertedFirstNums[cycle-3] = switchInteger(Integer.parseInt(firstNum));

                //Parse the rest of the line, ignoring the first integer
                int ind = 0;
                for(char c : line.substring(1).toCharArray()) {
                    switch(c) {
                    case ' ': //Skip all spaces in the line
                        break;
                    default: //Take following integers and saves them to num array
                        String num = "" + c;
                        nums[cycle-1][ind] = Integer.parseInt(num);
                        ind++;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                //Pick up first two lines 
                nums[cycle-1][0] = Integer.parseInt(line);
            }
        }

        scanInt.close();

        for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(i < 2) //Print first two numbers from first two lines
                System.out.printf("%d\n", nums[i][0]);  
            else {
                System.out.print(convertedFirstNums[i-2] + " : ");
                for(int j=0; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%d ", nums[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }

    public static String switchInteger(int i) {
        switch(i) {
        case 0: return "add ";
        case 1: return "sub ";
        case 2: return "mult";
        case 3: return "div ";
        }
        return "err ";
    }
}
```